# Append values to multidimensional array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a multidimensional array called 'data' that is initialised as so:

```
var data = [[String]]()
```

I can add all of my required arrays to this without issue.

The problem I am facing is that I need all of the included arrays to have the same number of values (I am creating a spreadsheet and I need to have the same number of 'columns' in each array). To do this I am trying to:

1. Find the count of the longest array
2. Append a number of "" (i.e. blank values) to the end of each array to equal the max count

I am having zero success finding out how to do either of these things. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a matrix like structure. [see this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. Will look into that. Not come across that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `max` function over `data` to get the number of elements of the longest array.

And then you can iterate over each element of the array and append `""` until it reaches the desired size.

Here you have an example:

```
var data = [[String]]()

data = [["aaa", "bbb"], ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["aaa"]]

var longestArrayCount = data.max { $0.count < $1.count }?.count ?? 0

for (index, _) in data.enumerated() {
    data[index].append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: "", count: longestArrayCount - data[index].count))
}

print(data)
```

> Output: [["aaa", "bbb", ""], ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["aaa", "", ""]]

**Update**

Applied change suggested by @BallpointBen

Comment: It would be be more efficient to do `data[index].append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: "", count: longestArrayCount - data[index].count))`

Comment: I totally agree :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you both! :)